# INTERNAL: gRPC frame header malformed: reserved bits not zero

Tags: grpc, grpc-java, envoyproxy

I am sending data of type application/grpc over HTTP using Envoys http-grpc bridge and calling a grpc service. This is what Lyft uses internally btw for its apis. It needs to be in the following format:

1 byte: 0, 4 byte network/bigindian length of grpc data, grpc data.

Here is my code:

```
private static void grpcPostRESTAPI() throws Exception
{
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

  String content = "//x00//x00//x00//x00//x15{“message”:”Hello”}";

try
{
    //Define a postRequest request
    HttpPost postRequest = new   HttpPost("http://10.10.xx.xx:31313/com.test.echo.EchoService/echo");

    //Set the API media type in http content-type header
    postRequest.addHeader("content-type", "application/grpc");

    //Set the request post body
    StringEntity userEntity = new StringEntity(content);
    postRequest.setEntity(userEntity);

    //Send the request; It will immediately return the response in    HttpResponse object if any
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

    //verify the valid error code first
    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
     if (statusCode != 201)
     {
           throw new RuntimeException("Failed with HTTP error code : "  + statusCode);
    }
  }
finally
  {
    //Important: Close the connect
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
   }
```

}

Within the GRPC Service I am seeing the following error:

```
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerStream$TransportState deframeFailed
WARNING: Exception processing message
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: gRPC frame header malformed:  reserved bits not zero
 at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:524)
 at  io.grpc.internal.MessageDeframer.processHeader(MessageDeframer.java:377)
 at io.grpc.internal.MessageDeframer.deliver(MessageDeframer.java:267)
 at io.grpc.internal.MessageDeframer.request(MessageDeframer.java:161)
 at  io.grpc.internal.AbstractStream$TransportState.requestMessagesFromDeframer(AbstractStream.java:205)
```

Here is the GRPC Server Code that is processing this:

```
 private static final int HEADER_LENGTH = 5;
 private static final int COMPRESSED_FLAG_MASK = 1;
 private static final int RESERVED_MASK = 0xFE;
```

Where the exception is thrown:

```
  private void processHeader() {
     int type = nextFrame.readUnsignedByte();
     if ((type & RESERVED_MASK) != 0) {
     throw Status.INTERNAL.withDescription(
         "gRPC frame header malformed: reserved bits not zero")
        .asRuntimeException();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

your should use RPC request instead of post a string:

```
 String content = "//x00//x00//x00//x00//x15{“message”:”Hello”}";
```

Comment: mode=grpcwebtext: The default generated code sends the payload in the grpc-web-text format.
Content-type: application/grpc-web-text
Payload are base64-encoded.
Both unary and server streaming calls are supported.
 
mode=grpcweb: A binary protobuf format is also supported.
Content-type: application/grpc-web+proto
Payload are in the binary protobuf format.
Only unary calls are supported for now.